# Count all possible paths from top left to bottom right of a mXn matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I should return number of possible paths from top left to bottom right  in an n*m matrix.
here is my code.

```
class Solution {
 public:
 map<pair<int,int>,long long int>mp;
   long long int numberOfPaths(int m, int n){
       if(n==1 || m==1)
       {
           return 1;
       }
       if(mp[make_pair(n,m)]!=0)
       return mp[make_pair(n,m)];
       mp[make_pair(n,m)]=numberOfPaths(n-1,m)+numberOfPaths(n,m-1);
       return mp[make_pair(n,m)];
   }
};
```

i got many solutions for this problem but i am interested in finding whats wrong in my code.
And i got wrong answer for input 19 and 71.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, especially ones that add no useful information. Your solution uses brute-force recursion, which often fails in practice. Play with the problem with pencil and paper, and you will soon see a much faster algorithm.

Comment: What's the expected answer and what is your program returning?

Comment: For input 19 and 71  . expected output :809936179    and my code output : 2418561960739869780

Comment: @doddi-girish see answer below. Your expected output is wrong for the problem statement. Please mark it as the answer if it helped you and answered the question.

Comment: @Doddigirish did you not see the modulus condition mentioned for the output? If you did, why didn't you mention it in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Your expected answer is wrong. The correct answer for input 19 and 71 is indeed 2418561960739869780.

Long answer:

Firstly, always keep code formatted - it helps yourself and the reader of such questions gather some motivation to read the question. Here is a slightly better formatted version:

```
class Solution {
public:
    map<pair<int, int>, long long int> mp;
    long long int numberOfPaths(int m, int n) {
        if(n == 1 || m == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        if(mp[make_pair(n, m)] != 0) return mp[make_pair(n, m)];
        mp[make_pair(n, m)] = numberOfPaths(n-1, m) + numberOfPaths(n, m-1);
        return mp[make_pair(n, m)];
    }
};
```

Secondly, always try and include reproducible code. When you only share a class definition, it will be hard for the reader to understand how you are using it.

Thirdly, I understand you are doing this as part of dynamic programming. But this approach is brute-force (as pointed in an earlier comment already). The mathematical solution to this is `(m-1) + (n-1) C (m-1)` since you have as many combinations. This computes faster as well since multiplication instead of repeated addition is optimised.

`88 C 18` is indeed 2418561960739869780.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the Mod 10^9 + 7 thing here , Read the quesiton carefully it must be there that to avoid overflows you have to take the ans mod  10^9 +7